# Search not finding anything even when matching text is highlighted?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Just tried searching for a keyword in an XSLT file and it returned no results, despite highlighting the word about a dozen times in the file anyway.

[image: Error Box Example]

Visual Studio clearly thinks the word cannot be found in the file, yet to the left you can see it's also highlighted matching text. "Find" and "Find All" return the same results. I haven't made any changes to my settings, so I don't know where to go prodding for search options to see if something's been changed by company policy or some other similarly daft reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be running up against a slight anomaly in the Quick Find functionality. When you first select Quick Find, if you have text selected in the editor window, the selected text appears as the search phrase and all instances are highlighted. But if you turn on a filter (such as Case Sensitive or Whole Word), some (possibly all) of the highlighted text instances no longer match the search string.

Try this:

1. Highlight a word in your code.
2. Click **Find and Replace** > **Quick Find**. All instances of the word are highlighted.
3. Now turn on **Match Case**, and change one letter in the search box so it is a capital letter.
4. Click **Find**. All instances of the word remain highlighted, but the "No results" dialog appears.

The problem is compounded by the fact that the little filter icons in the Quick Find window are difficult to interpret.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can clearly see I haven't enabled any filters in the quick find (Match Case, Whole Word, etc) and even when the case matches and I search the whole word it's getting no results. Are there some over-riding settings I can find to mess with?

Comment: According to this post: http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2008/10/17/125902.aspx ... try pressing Ctrl+Scroll Lock.

Comment: Also this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/40c9ad4a-8cee-4f3f-b420-c7cc0463942a/visual-studio-2012-find-in-files-not-displaying-files?forum=vsx